# How to pass data into the nested component's scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller with a list of request/response pairs and trying to render it using components(directives).

It seems like only string attributes make it into the component's scope, objects get discarded.

See *broken* code here: http://jsfiddle.net/4QWMq/

Any ideas how to fix that and make lists appear?

Comment: My previous attempt to do that worked better, but it didn't have a controller, all data was in the list component: http://jsfiddle.net/F8z2b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was camel case that bit me.

Making all attribute names lower case fixed the problem.
Angular templates are valid HTML, and attribute names are case insensitive in HTML.

Updated fiddle works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/4QWMq/2/